# How to randomly replace a specific element in a nested list?

Tags: python, list, random, replace, element

I have a list of lists. How do I create a function which randomly replaces an instance of 10 with another number?

```
lst = [ [10, 100, 10 ], [10, 1000, 10], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 10, 0] ]
```

Here is my code. I can only manage to get a flattened list instead of a nested list. How do I get a nested list, and is there a more efficient way?

```
import random

def random_replace10(num, lst): # replaces 10 with num
    indexes = []
    flattened = [num for row in lst for num in row]
    for ind, ele in enumerate(flattened):
        if ele == 10:
            indexes.append(ind)

    random_index = random.sample(indexes, 1)[0]
    flattened[random_index] = num
    return flattened           #Returns a flattened list instead of a nested list.


print(random_replace10(2, lst))

>>> [ [10, 100, 2 ], [10, 1000, 10], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 10, 0] ]

print(random_replace10(91, lst))

>>> [ [10, 100, 2 ], [10, 1000, 10], [100, 100000, 100], [91, 10, 0] ]
```

Comment: Double `for` loop? What is your current trial?

Comment: the instances of 10 should be randomly replaced by what values? random values?

Comment: Should the replacement be *in place*? E.g. should `random_replace10(2, lst)` then `print(lst)` result in the updated list being printed, or should `random_replace10()` return a *new* list?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It does not matter.

Comment: @seralouk Apologies for not being specific. I need to replace a single instance of 10 with a value of my choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to find how many `10` values you have, then choose which one to replace with a `random.randrange()` option. I used `itertools.count()` to keep a running counter to match the selected instance:

```
from itertools import count
import random


def random_replace10(num, lst):
    selected = random.randrange(sum(sum(1 for i in sub if i == 10) for sub in lst))
    counter = count()
    return [
        [num if i == 10 and next(counter) == selected else i for i in sub] 
        for sub in lst
    ]
```

This replaces exactly one `10` value with `num`, no more, no less, and creates a *new* list. The old list is left untouched.

You can also make the replacement in-place, but in that case I'd return `None` (just like other mutating methods on `list` would do, such as `list.append()`, etc.). In that case, record the locations of the `10` values first, use `random.choice()` to pick one one of those locations:

```
import random

def random_replace10_inplace(num, lst):
    locations = [(i, j) for i, sub in enumerate(lst) for j, v in enumerate(sub) if v == 10]
    outer, inner = random.choice(locations)
    lst[outer][inner] = num
```

Demo of the first version:

```
>>> lst = [[10, 100, 10], [10, 1000, 10], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 10, 0]]
>>> random_replace10(2, lst)
[[10, 100, 10], [10, 1000, 2], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 10, 0]]
>>> random_replace10(2, lst)
[[10, 100, 10], [10, 1000, 10], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 2, 0]]
>>> random_replace10(91, lst)
[[10, 100, 91], [10, 1000, 10], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 10, 0]]
>>> random_replace10(91, lst)
[[10, 100, 10], [10, 1000, 91], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 10, 0]]
```

and of the in-place version:

```
>>> lst = [[10, 100, 10], [10, 1000, 10], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 10, 0]]
>>> random_replace10_inplace(2, lst)
>>> lst
[[10, 100, 10], [10, 1000, 2], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 10, 0]]
>>> random_replace10_inplace(2, lst)
>>> lst
[[10, 100, 10], [2, 1000, 2], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 10, 0]]
>>> random_replace10_inplace(91, lst)
>>> lst
[[10, 100, 10], [2, 1000, 2], [100, 100000, 100], [91, 10, 0]]
>>> random_replace10_inplace(91, lst)
>>> lst
[[91, 100, 10], [2, 1000, 2], [100, 100000, 100], [91, 10, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```
import random

lst = [[10, 100, 10], [10, 1000, 10], [100, 100000, 100], [10, 10, 0]]


def random_replace10(num, lst):
    ten_index = []
    for i, item in enumerate(lst):
        for j, inner_item in enumerate(item):
            if inner_item == 10:
                ten_index.append((i, j))

    i, j = random.choice(ten_index)
    lst[i][j] = num
    print(lst)
```